# vuejs dynamic component throw error for v-bind:is, error is Property or method ... is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, components

Code in the file:

```
<template>
  <component v-bind:is="bbc"></component>
</template>

<script>

import bbc from './bbc.vue';

  export default {
    name: 'ShowRoom2',
  };
</script>
```

`./bbc.vue`

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'bbc',
    props: {
      msg: String,
    },
    mounted() {
      console.log('bbc is mounted');
    },
    render() {
      if (this.func) this.func();
      return (
        <div class="bbcMyClass">
          <h1>bbc: <span>Pal</span> <span>{this.msg}</span></h1>
        </div>
      )
    }
  };
</script>
```

To reproduce

1. git clone git@github.com:adamchenwei/vue-hoc-playground.git
2. go to `src/components/ShowRoom2.vue`
3. yarn install && yarn serve
4. observe error in the local browser

[image]

Comment: i think you have to set `is` without `:`

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim sorry, I may misunderstood what you said, but document says otherwise (granted, Vue document is not very up to date for some parts) https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the scope in the template is not the same as the script scope. If you need some data, you need to declare it inside the 'component' definition part of the code. For your case, I guess the 'data' property should work

```
import bbc from './bbc.vue';

export default {
  name: 'ShowRoom2',
  data() {
    return {
      bbc: bbc,
    };
  },
};
```

However, the template part of your code also looks weird. Could you explain what you're trying to do ?

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. I am trying to use dynamic component as a alternative to create HOC, which involving adding class name and such into a wrapped component, which I suppose that `<component>` thingie can help to do? so next step I am going to do is <component class="something" data-something="somethingelse"...><...>

Comment: HOC ? I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: it kinda does similiar stuff! I am going for this approach instead of HOC for now (since its not very well implemented in Vuejs, various articles show that). Thanks!